# how can I write special characters as ascii code in javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, ascii, special-characters

This is my code :

```
$("#ocultar").text("Mostrar Menú");
```

Obviously for some reason the character **ú** is not recognized ? so what can I do ?
this code works but not for special characters :

```
var res = String.fromCharCode(65);
```

You can see the result here : [image]

Comment: What is the character encoding of the page? If not utf8, try &uacute;

Comment: Seems fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/ccUP2/

Comment: Check you meta tag for charset, the code is fine and should work.

Comment: Use character encoding as `<meta charset="utf-8" />`

Comment: @KunJ I change the charset , it works , but now it does not recognize this sign ”

Comment: OK, then font family you are using may not have it. Try 'Arial Unicode MS' once for test, it has that character.

Comment: I removed the font- family , but stil the same , instead of  ” I got this sign �